# Writing unit test cases for vertx database access (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, junit, vert.x

I am writing Unit test cases but struck at writing Unit test cases for database access.

I found following links but still didn't understand how to use it. where to write initial schema and configure.
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/blob/d96e53f80c0066b377c43efbd1c6466bb0d06e51/vertx-pg-client/README.adoc

```
it says > mvn test -Dembedded.postgres.version=9.6

 https://dzone.com/articles/using-embedded-postgresql-databases-for-unit-testi
```

My Queries:

- How do we write Unit test cases in data base access level
- I am trying this embedded database approach is it correct? or is there any other way.

Please guide me how do we write UT for this senario.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) if you can run containers on your development machine.

Testcontainers lets you configure and start various databases in a container.

Answer (score 0):

Or just embeded database like [h2](https://www.baeldung.com/h2-embedded-db-data-storage) (little old way)